# Flutter - Error building context after await function

Tags: flutter

I have this function

```
runBookingFunction(BuildContext context, int id, String startCoordinates, String endCoordinates) async {



//then open loader
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (context) => const SimpleDialog(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ],
      )
  );

  bool response = await confirmRideBooking(startCoordinates, endCoordinates, id);

  //pop dialog

  Navigator.of(context).pop();

  if(response){
    successDialog(context, 'Suucess');
  }
  else{
    failDialog(context, 'fail');
  }




  //run event
  // BlocProvider.of<HomeViewBloc>(context)
  //     .add(ConfirmBookingEvent(startCoordinates, endCoordinates, id));

}
```

From the code that tries to remove the loading dialog i get an error that context is null and beyond that the dialogs i try to run do not with the same errors.
This causes the loading dialog to keep running and the value of the response to not be handled.

How do i fix it?